# Pass array values to javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I have a cshtml file with a Javascript function which accepts an array of values as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var NamesAndAges = [
      [Name, Age1, Year, 4],
      [Name, Age1, Year, 5],
      [Name, Age1, Year, 3],
      [Name, Age1, Year, 2],
      [Name, Age1, Year, 1]
    ];
....
.... left out for brevity
</script>
```

I then have a for each loop which is building the array for the above function.

```
 @foreach (var a in Model.Children.Where("Visible"))
 {
    var Name = a.Name
    var Age = a.Age
    var Year = a.Year
 }
```

How could i pass in the values from the `foreach` loop (i know i may have to declare them outside of the loop) into the Javascript?

I've seen a few threads but cant find any that explain how to pass an array (or theyve not been answered)?

Comment: Do you want an array of arrays, or an array of objects? - you can use `var data = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Children))'` to create an array of objects in your collection

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing, are you trying to get data from C# to javascript? Do you want to generate javascript dynamically? Also, if you have treads that you found while researching please link to them so we can see them as well.

Comment: @stephen Muecke I would say an array of arrays as there would be multiple children and for each child I would need the name,age etc

Comment: It that case you do what an array of objects (which is what your model is). Just you the code in my first comment inside a script and then you can access values using `var age = data[0].age;`

Comment: Thanks!! Will give this a shot and get back. How would that code know which field in passing in? I.e. Name, age - '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Children))'

Comment: It passing all the properties of each item in your collection.

Comment: That did the trick!! Feel free to add it as an answer and i will mark it as so